# PHP Login System displaying code on Webpage

Tags: php, mysql, html, css

I have been trying to make a login system via PHP. When I try to run it, all code from `($errors as $error)` is shown on the actual webpage. I've been trying to test it for a few hours.

Note: When I change the `>` to `<`, it works fine in `if(count($errors) > 0){`
but that makes it so even if there are errors with passwords/usernames they can still press enter.

Any help please! Code is provided.

```
<?
    mysql_pconnect('localhost', 'root', '');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        if(!$_POST['submit']) {
    ?>
            <form action="index.php" method="post">
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Username:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="username" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Password:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="password" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Retype Password:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="passwordconf" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>
                            Email Address:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="email" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center">
                            <input type="submit" value="Create User" name="submit" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
    <?php
        } else {     
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $passwordconf = $_POST ['passwordconf'];
            $email = $_POST ['email'];

            $errors = array();

            if(!$username) {

                $errors[1] = "Please enter a username.";

            }
            if(!$password) {

                $errors[2] = "Please enter a password.";

            }
            if(!$passwordconf) {

                $errors[3] = "Please retype password.";

            }
            if(!$email) {

                $errors[4] = "Please enter an email address.";

            }
            if($password != $passwordconf) {

                $errors[5] = "Passwords do not match.";

            }
            if(count($errors) > 0){

                foreach($errors as $error) {

                    echo "$error<br>";

                }

            } else {
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'users' . 'user_info'
                ('username', 'password', 'email', 'user_admin_level')
                VALUES ('".$username."', '".md5($password)."', '".$email."', '1');");
            }
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you see in your browser's address bar?

Comment: What do you mean with "is shown on the actual webpage"?

Comment: file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/LoginSystem.php

Comment: Nerd, it shows the table where you can type, but then underneath it it shows ""; } else { mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'users' . 'user_info' ('username', 'password', 'email', 'user_admin_level') VALUES ('".$username."', '".md5($password)."', '".$email."', '1');"); } } ?> "

Comment: @RickRoll'd that's why you see your code. It should be like `http://localhost/LoginSystem.php`.

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov, it says Object not found!

Comment: first install wamp on your PC

Comment: @RickRoll'd configure your web server, install it first of course, `WAMP`, `XAMPP`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call PHP-files without a webserver serving them. PHP is the acronym for "PHP Hyptertext Preprocessor", which implies that there is a preprocessor needed to interpret those files.

Try using [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html), that's a lightweight server system that comes with an apache web-server, a mySQL-server and PHP- and PERL-support.

When using XAMPP already put your php-file into the htdocs-folder of your XAMPP-installation and then call `http://localhost/yourscript.php`.

Answer (score 1):

@Rick Roll'd

open your php page like this

```
http://localhost/path_to_page/LoginSystem.php
```

Don't store your page on `Desktop` save php page in `www/htdocs` directory.

Comment: why downvote?? he is opening `php` page directly not from document root.

Comment: maybe because http:\\ is not valid protocol?

Answer (score 1):

You can't run PHP like that. You need web server to run PHP. Follow these steps,

Using XAMPP is very easy. Follow these steps -

1. Install and run the [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) application. Turn on Apache & MySQL (if your application needs database) services through it.
2. Click on 'Explore' button on the XAMPP control panel - in the window that opens, check for htdocs folder.
3. htdocs folder is the one where all your PHP scripts should lie. This is the folder that Apache points to.
4. You might want to create a separate folder inside /htdocs/ folder to save all your PHP programs. Let's call it 'myprograms'.
5. Save your php script in /htdocs/myprograms folder. (Ex. test.php)
6. Now, start your webbrowser and type following address: `http://localhost/myprograms/test.php`

Your browser will now execute the script and show you the output.

Answer (score 1):

from URL :file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/LoginSystem.php you are accessing a file which will not be interpreted by the PHP Interpreter (wamp or lamp).

You need to install a php server(wamp, xamp or Lamp ) and put your file in respective webserver directories then execute you file by entering url like this :

```
localhost/LoginSystem.php
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

try displaying $errors and the size (**print_r($errors); echo count($errors);**) to see if it really has no content.

Also I'd change **if(!$username)** to **if (empty($username))**
+ it's very bad practice to accept userinput as $var = $_POST['varname'].

Also an array always starts with key 0 (you're manually assigning it to key 1). To simply add elements to an array use **$errors[] = "you forgot something";**

Personally I'd advise you to choose a login/session class from a project like Drupal/cakePHP/phpBB/...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should place the HTML code first. An empty field is not always an error. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action= "<?php $_SERVER[ 'PHP_SELF' ] ?>" method="post">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>
        Username: </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="username" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Password: </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="password" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Retype Password: </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="passwordconf" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Email Address: </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="email" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center">
        <input type="submit" value="Create User" name="submit" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

</body>
</html>


<?php
if ( isset ( $_POST[ 'submit' ] ) ) {

  if ( $_POST[ 'username' ] ) {
    $username = $_POST[ 'username' ];
    $username = trim( $username) ; // Remove spaces
  }
  else {
    echo "Please enter a username.<br /><br />";
    die;
  }

 // And so on....

  mysql_pconnect( 'localhost', 'root', '' );
  mysql_query( "INSERT INTO 'users' . 'user_info'
                ('username', 'password', 'email', 'user_admin_level')
                VALUES ('" . $username . "', '" . md5( $password ) . "', '" . $email . "', '1');" );
}
?>
```

You can test it installing a local server, as suggested,  or uploading the file to your ISP server.

Hope this helps.